# Fluent NHibernate different Conventions for different base types

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions, conventions

At this moment we are keeping all Entities and Mappings into same assembly. Our entities derived from a basic class Entity which is an EntityWithTypedId

Also we are having a table name Convention telling to pluralize the table names.

Now I want to create other two base types e.q. AggregateRootEntity and AggregateEntity, both derive from Entity. 
And I would like to create two set of conventions for both base entities:

Let's say:
For for all entities derived from AggregateRootEntity tables should be prefixed with "ag_" and Id is incremental generated, but for all entities derived from AggregateEntity tables should be prefixed with "a_" and Ids should be assigned.

Is it possible to Set Conventions based on some conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with multiple conventions, each checking for a specific type in their Accept methods

something like:

```
public class LegacyEntityTableConvention : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{
  public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
  {
    criteria.Expect(x => x.EntityType.IsAny(typeof(OldClass), typeof(AnotherOldClass)));
  }

  public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
  {
    instance.Table("tbl_" + instance.EntityType.Name);
  }
}
```

Just a block of code out of the FNH Wiki
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Acceptance_criteria